# About 'Refer-To' header

Tags: node.js, http, erlang, sip

I have a `Refer-To` header:

```
Refer-To: <additional.session.xfer@sccas.home1.net?Target-Dialog=ksdjfhwrklf%3Bremote-tag=676723565%3Blocal-tag=45418454&Require=tdialog&From=tel:+1-237-555-1111&To=tel:+1-987-654-3210&Content-Type=application%2Fsdp&body=v%3D0%0D%0Ao%3D-%202987933623%202987933623%20IN%20IP6%205555::ggg:fff:aaa:bbb%0D%0As%3D-%0D%0Ac%3DIN%20IP6%205555::ggg:fff:aaa:bbb%0D%0At%3D0%200%0D%0Aaudio%203456%20RTP%2FAVP%2097%2096%0D%0Ab%3DAS:25.4%0D%0Aa%3Drtpmap:97%20AMR%0D%0Aa%3Dfmtp:97%20mode-set%3D0%2C2%2C5%2C7%3B%20mode-change-period%3D2%0D%0Aa%3Dmaxptime:20%0D%0A>
```

In this header, there are a lot of `%3B` or `%0D` and so on.

I want to konw how to convert them to human-readable?

Answer (score 2):

This is called URL encoding. What you are looking for exists in Erlang as [http_uri:decode/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/http_uri.html#decode-1) and in Javascript as [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Answer (score -2):

Here is a C method to convert all %XX:

Each occurence of %XX represent an hexadecimal value of a character
in ascii format. For example, *"%3D" is "="*

```
void
__osip_uri_unescape (char *string)
{
  size_t alloc = strlen (string) + 1;
  unsigned char in;
  int index = 0;
  unsigned int hex;
  char *ptr;

  ptr = string;
  while (--alloc > 0) {
    in = *ptr;
    if ('%' == in) {
      /* encoded part */
      if (alloc > 2 && sscanf (ptr + 1, "%02X", &hex) == 1) {
        in = (unsigned char) hex;
        if (*(ptr + 2) && ((*(ptr + 2) >= '0' && *(ptr + 2) <= '9') || (*(ptr + 2) >= 'a' && *(ptr + 2) <= 'f') || (*(ptr + 2) >= 'A' && *(ptr + 2) <= 'F'))) {
          alloc -= 2;
          ptr += 2;
        }
        else {
          alloc -= 1;
          ptr += 1;
        }
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }

    string[index++] = in;
    ptr++;
  }
  string[index] = 0;            /* terminate it */
}
```